# Photogallery is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, photo-gallery, prettyphoto

I have a photo gallery, it works on all browsers except IE, the thumbnails do not appear.

I was thinking of trying to find another gallery to use online, but I figured I'll try here first. any help is very appreciated!

here is the link
http://lockheedlee.com/meadowland/gallery.html

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you we need you show us some code, something that you already tried. In this particular case I recommend that you choose a different photo gallery because that link seems to be experimental (it is yours?). They have **lorem ipsum** text http://lockheedlee.com/meadowland/about.html

Comment: @Gepser He's using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html) - it's very good, but he is on `v1.5.03` and I believe it is `v2.2.2`, but I doubt that is the issue. I would bet it is the implementation of it. -- Please explain what *doesn't work* and which version of ie

Comment: you should find it your self , you can find many js library on google.

Comment: @Gepser, yes it's experimental. The person wanted me to use this template that they found and I played around with it to what they want, but the thumbnails don't appear on IE. I tried contacting the people that created the template but no luck.

Comment: @Quoid the thumbnails on that page doesn't appear on IE (I'm on IE 11) but the thumbnails appear perfectly on other browsers like Firefox & Chrome etc.

Comment: Well, I am on Chrome and I didn't see any thumbnail

Comment: @Gepser that's weird, it works perfectly on my Chrome, the thumbnails should read "for placement only", I'm still waiting for my friend the real images.

Comment: Oh, never mind, that's the thumbnail, I thought it was something else.

Comment: @Quoid you were right. it was the preloader that was giving me the problems. I just got rid of the preloader script and it now works

Comment: @lokey718 be sure to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) below if it helped you, glad I was of service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working in `ie11` has to do with the way you are preloading your images, likely with the `jQuery.preloader.js`

The inline style `visibility: hidden` is not properly getting removed from the `img` elements in `ie11`. I don't believe this is an issue with [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co), but I *would* recommend updating to the newest version and for the time being, find a new `img` preloader, like [this one](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded), by the same developer as isotope.

[image: ie11-visibility]